# Facing some issue when trying to delete object from array - mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to delete object from an array. If the object value match that object will be deleted from the database.
Here is my database example:

```json
[{
        _id: "621773f39ec6fe3a3728d686",
        label: "size",
        slug: "size",
        vendor: "admin",
        options: [
            {
                label: "M",
                value: "M"
            },
            {
                label: "XXL",
                value: "XXL"
            },
            {
                label: "XL",
                value: "XL"
            },
            {
                label: "S",
                value: "S"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

This is my code:

```js
        // DELETE FILED FROM ATTRIBUTE
        app.put('/dashboard/attribute/fieldDelete/:id', async (req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id
            const { value } = req.body
            unityMartAttributes.updateOne({ value: value }, { $pull: { options: { _id: objectId(id) } } })

        })
```

Expected output: value: "M" matched that's why that object removed

```json
[{
        _id: "621773f39ec6fe3a3728d686",
        label: "size",
        slug: "size",
        vendor: "admin",
        options: [

            {
                label: "XXL",
                value: "XXL"
            },
            {
                label: "XL",
                value: "XL"
            },
            {
                label: "S",
                value: "S"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

Comment: what is your issue ? Any specific error ?

Comment: need more clarity on the question. what do you want to delete here? 
Do you want to pull items from options array? do you want to delete the document itself if any match is found on the options array?  can you please clarify your use case. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
app.put('/dashboard/attribute/fieldDelete/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id
  const { value } = req.body

  await unityMartAttributes.updateOne({ "_id": id }, {
    "$pull": {
      "options": {
        "value": value
      }
    }
  });

}
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cejU5nOMHOK)

Comment: I don't want to delete whole options, I want to delete only one object which is matched with the `value`

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?